# VBA Check columns match previous version

Tags: excel, vba

Have almost no experience with VBA but wondering if there is a way to validate if a Excel worksheet has the same column structure as another. Additionally do this for multiple Excel sheets with different structures at the same time in a single script.

Example worksheet A1 columns [A,B,C] needs to reconcile with Worksheet A2 and Worksheet B1 columns [D,E,F] need to reconcile with Worksheet B2. Flagging an error if any of the columns do not match with their previous version.

Comment: A similar question was asked here today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093675/how-to-compare-excel-files?noredirect=1#comment73268822_43093675

Comment: Thanks Callum - will take a look although on surface level it looks like only works with one file comparison in reality I may have 50 to compare but this looks like a good starting point, thank you!